# How to implement mouse leave trigger in WPF?

Tags: wpf

How to implement mouse leave trigger in WPF?

I tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
      <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
              Duration="0:0:0.2"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight"
              To="90"  />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
      <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
              Duration="0:0:1"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight"  />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: works fine for me, what are you expecting to happen when you animate `MaxHeight`

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not tell us anything.  What is the expected behavior, and what is the behavior you are actually seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and it all works fine,

I suspect you have not set an initial value for `MaxHeight` and the animation if failing to animate it because its value is `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`

Here is the code I tested below incase it helps

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" MaxHeight="100">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight" To="90" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight"  />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```